# Wifi works really slow

Tags: wireless

im new to ubuntu. I have lenovo ideapad 310 with dual boot (ubuntu 16.04. win10) and 50 Mbps internet. on win10 wifi works fine, while on ubuntu 16.04 is always at speed aroud 2 Mbps. i tried something like this:

sudo gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf ( and then deleted some stuff at hosts: files dns) but nothing changed.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4035]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: How did you measure the speed?

Comment: with speedtest.net ,  sometimes it wont even load the page